# JavaScript/jQuery - setInterval parando execução de outras funções do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arduino, setinterval

estou enfrentando um problema que está me deixando louco já. É o seguinte.

Estou capturando dados json de um servidor externo em cross-domain, preciso que esses dados sejam atualizados de 5 em 5 segundos. Consegui fazer o loop e deixar essa função sendo executada. Porém, eu possuo um botão na mesma página, que quando está no tempo do setInterval, o botão simplesmente não funciona. Gostaria de saber uma alternativa para fazer um loop, mantendo atualizado e não perder as outras funções do JavaScript enquanto o setInterval está em execução.

Desde já, obrigado.

Função de teste:

```
/* DEFINIÇÕES DE VARIÁVEIS */
var lightStatus;

function toggleLight(lightState){
    
    $.post("http://192.168.0.109/LED", {}, function(){
        
    });
    
    
    if(lightState){
        lightStatus = false;
    } else {
        lightStatus = true;
    }
    console.log("Status: " + lightStatus);
}

setInterval("updateSensors()", 5000);

function updateSensors(){
    $.post("http://192.168.0.109/sensors", {}, function(ESP8266){
            //console.log(data);
            lightStatus = ESP8266.lightStatus;
            console.log("lightStatus> " +ESP8266.lightStatus);
            console.log("Temperatura> " +ESP8266.temperatura);
            console.log("Umidade> "+ ESP8266.umidadeAr);
            //console.log("Umidade do solo> "+ ESP8266.umidadeSolo);
        }, "json");
}

$(function(){
    
    updateSensors();
    
    console.log("var lightStatus: "+lightStatus);
    
    $("div#lightSwitch").on("click", function(){
        toggleLight(lightStatus);
    })
    
    
    
});
```

Comment: `setInterval` pega dois argumentos como paremtro, o primeiro é uma função e o segundo o tempo, você está passando uma string que é o nome da sua função é o tempo, e provavelmente está gerando algum erro no seu console. Tenta passar algo como `setInterval(updateSensors, 5000)` sem aspas

Comment: Na verdade esse `setInterval` funciona sim. No caso ele vai passar a string num `eval`. Entretanto Ellysson, seria realmente melhor se você escrevesse `setInterval(updateSensors, 5000);`.

Comment: Ellysson, o que acontece é que a página congela a cada 5 segundos (caso 1) ou só o tal botão não funciona após a primeira chamada do `updateSensors` (caso 2)?

Comment: Se for o caso 1, você tem alguma outra rotina aí que toma muito tempo de execução. Vc deve melhora-la ou pode até colocar um pouco de assincronicidade para não trancar o main loop por tempo perceptível. *OU* você pode colocar o código pesado num `WebWorker`.